Derived graph from edge-path incidence of a graph
I have directed, acyclic, connected, s,t-multi-graphs (single source, single sink).
I can take say graph $G=(V,E)$ and form another graph $G'=(V',E')$ (similar I guess to a line graph) where $V'$ consists of all the edges and paths (from s to t) in $G$. We have an edge in $G'$ from edge $e$ to path $p$ if the path uses the edge. So, a graph of the edge-path incidence. So, $G'$ is bipartite.
So, for example 1->2,1->2,2->3,1->3 is an example s,t-graph with vertex s labeled 1 and vertex t labeled 3. We have 3 paths from s to t in this graph and we can label them $p_1,...,p_3$. We can label the 4 edges in the graph $e_1,...,e_4$.
Our derived graph H would be: $e_1$->$p_1$,$e_3$->$p_1$,$e_2$->$p_2$,$e_3$->$p_2$,$e_4$->$p_3$
$e_1,e_2$ are the edges from 1->2. $e_3$ is the edge from 2->3 and $e_4$ is the edge from 1->3.
I wish to enumerate graphs $G_i$ avoiding derivate graphs that are isomorphic $G'_i \not\equiv G'_j, i\ne j$
So my questions are if this derived edge-path incidence graph is something that's studied and if so what is it called?
Is it possible typically to be able to enumerate all graphs G avoiding isomorphisms in the derived graphs? Obviously there would be other restrictions on the graphs to make them a finite set.
